# Undo Operation in paint application

Tags: ios, undo

I am using this link(http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit) for making a paint application and I want to perform a undo operation as well.

I used this code to save every sketch made by the user in an mutable `array[completeLines]. These changes are done in touchesEnded method.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_tempDrawImage.bounds.size, NO,0.0);
[_tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tempDrawImage.frame.size.width, _tempDrawImage.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[completeLines addObject:image];
```

Now I am not able to remove these images stored in the mutable array from the main image.

Answer (score 0):

So, you might be halfway there.
If you have kept an array of each image drawn, then you just need to remove the last one, clear the main image (draw all white or whatever) if your array of images are not opaque, and draw the one before to the main image.

You could be fancier and keep the undone images temporarily as Redo options until new drawing is done. Just keep a stack of Redos, and if new drawing is done, clear the Redo stack.